# Cassandra-stress test: invalid parameter

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, stress-testing, cassandra-stress, cassandra-stress-tool

~/**cassandra-stress** **mixed** ratio\(write=5,read=1\) n=100000 **user profile**=./cassandra.yaml **duration**=15m 'ops\(insert=10\)' **cl**=QUORUM  **-rate** threads=100 **-mode** native cql3 port=9042 user=cassandra password=cassandra **-transport** truststore=/home/../../truststore.jks truststore-password="*********" keystore=/home/../../../cassandra-keystore.jks keystore-password="*******" ssl-protocol=****** ssl-alg=******* ssl-ciphers=************* **-node** $NODES **-port** native=9042 jmx=7199

Error: Invalid paramerter user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mixed` & `user` modes are mutually exclusive. You need to remove `mixed ratio\(write=5,read=1\) n=100000` part, specify queries & inserts inside the `.yaml` file, and then specify necessary ration as `ops` parameter, for example as: `ops\(insert=3,read1=1\) n=100000`

Comment: I don't have working cassandra right now, but I suspect that you can't mix together the `n=...` & `duration=` parameters.  You also may need to escape parentheses in `ops` parameters - notice the `\` (backslash) in my example